My UseEffect() function doesn't get released (memory leak)
I'm an Angular developer who's working on a new React app (I'm learning on the way). There's a concept I think I don't understand.
import './LeadPool.scss';
import SideMenuLayout from "../../layouts/side-menu/SideMenuLayout";
import {
  IonButton,
  IonCard,
  IonCardContent,
  IonChip,
  IonCol,
  IonRow,
  IonSearchbar,
  IonToggle, useIonLoading,
  useIonModal
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Table, TableColumnsType, Tooltip} from "antd";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {useService} from "../../store/service-provider/ServiceProvider";
import {LeadBo} from "../../services/lead-search/bos/leadBo";
import {PageBo} from "../../services/lead-search/bos/pageBo";
import {LeadPoolDataTypeInterface} from "./interfaces/lead-pool-data-type.interface";
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import LeadViewer from "../../components/lead-viewer/LeadViewer";
import {OverlayEventDetail} from "@ionic/react/dist/types/components/react-component-lib/interfaces";
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import pulsingAnimation from '../../assets/lotties/pulsing.json';

const LeadPool: React.FC = () => {

  const [datatable, setDatatable] = useState<LeadPoolDataTypeInterface[]>(null);
  const [pageLeadBoList, setPageLeadBoList] = useState<LeadBo[]>(null);
  const [selectedLeadBo, setSelectedLeadBo] = useState<LeadBo>(null);
  const services = useService();
  const { leadPoolId }  = useParams<{leadPoolId: string}>();
  const [presentLoading, dismissLoading] = useIonLoading();
  const [page, setPage] = useState<PageBo>({
    pageSize: 15,
    currentPage: 1,
    searchText: '',
    leadPoolId: leadPoolId,
    totalDocuments: 44,
    searchAllLeads: true,
  });
  const columns: TableColumnsType<LeadPoolDataTypeInterface> = [
    {
      title: 'Company',
      dataIndex: 'companyName',
      key: 'companyName',
      render: (value, record, index) =>
        <div>
          <a onClick={ (event)=> {
            startLeadViewer(record.id);
          }}>{ value }</a>
        </div>,
    },
    { title: 'Address', dataIndex: 'address', key: 'address' },
    {
      title: 'Social Media',
      dataIndex: 'socialMediaLinkList',
      key: 'socialMediaLinkList',
      render: (value, record, index) =>
        <div>
          { record.socialMediaLinkList.map( (socialMediaLink, index) => {
            return  (
              <Tooltip title={'Visit social'} key={record.id + '_' + index}>
                <a href={socialMediaLink.link}
                   target="_blank"
                   rel="noopener noreferrer">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    icon={socialMediaLink.icon}
                    size={"2x"}
                    color={'gray'}
                    className="ml-2"
                    onClick={ (event) => {
                      console.log('onClick event', event);
                    }}
                  />
                </a>
              </Tooltip>
            )
          })}
        </div>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Phones',
      dataIndex: 'phone',
      key: 'phone',
      render: (value, record, index) => {
        if(record.phoneList.length > 0) {
        return (
            <div>
              <IonChip
                color="tertiary"
              >
                { record.phoneList[0].phoneNumber }
                <b style={{marginLeft: '0.5em'}}>{(record.phoneList.length > 1) ? '(+' + record.phoneList.length + ')' : ''}</b>
              </IonChip>
            </div>
        )}
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Emails',
      dataIndex: 'email',
      key: 'email',
      render: (value, record, index) => {
        if(record.emailList.length > 0) {
          return (
            <div>
              <IonChip
                color="primary"
              >
                { record.emailList[0].email }
                <b style={{marginLeft: '0.5em'}}>{(record.emailList.length > 1) ? '(+' + record.emailList.length + ')' : ''}</b>
              </IonChip>
            </div>
          )}
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'Status',
      dataIndex: 'businessStatus',
      key: 'businessStatus',
      render: (value, record, index) => {
        if(record.isOperational) {
          return  <Lottie animationData={pulsingAnimation}
                          loop={true}
                          className="lead-pool-pulsing"
                  />
        }
      }
    },
  ];
  let isLeadViewerOpening = false;

  function generateDatatable(leadBoList: LeadBo[]) {
    const datatableList: LeadPoolDataTypeInterface[] = [];
    leadBoList.forEach( leadBo => {
      const datatable: LeadPoolDataTypeInterface = {
        key: leadBo.id,
        id: leadBo.id,
        companyName: leadBo.name,
        address: leadBo.fullAddress,
        socialMediaLinkList: leadBo.getSocialMediaLinkList(),
        phoneList: leadBo.getPhoneList(),
        emailList: leadBo.getEmailList(),
        isOperational: leadBo.isOperational(),
      }
      datatableList.push(datatable);
    })
    return datatableList;
  }


  function refreshPage(pageLocal: PageBo) {
    console.log('Kick11111 refreshPage', null);
      // setDatatable(null)
      // services.leadSearchService.getLeadPool(pageLocal).then((leadPoolBo) => {
      //   setPageLeadBoList(leadPoolBo.leadList);
      //   setDatatable( generateDatatable(leadPoolBo.leadList) );
      //   setPage( { ...pageLocal, totalDocuments: leadPoolBo.totalDocumentCount });
      // });
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Kick222222 useEffect', null);
    refreshPage( page )
  }, []);


  const [presentLeadViewer, dismissLeadViewer] = useIonModal(LeadViewer, {
    onDismiss: (data: string, role: string) => {
      dismissLeadViewer(data, role)
    },
    leadBo: selectedLeadBo,
  });


  async function startLeadViewer(leadId: string){
    if(isLeadViewerOpening) { return }
    isLeadViewerOpening = true;
    presentLoading('Loading...');
    console.log('Kick11111 pageLeadBoList', pageLeadBoList);
    setSelectedLeadBo( pageLeadBoList.find( lead => lead.id == leadId) );
    presentLeadViewer({
      onWillDismiss: (ev: CustomEvent<OverlayEventDetail>) => {},
      cssClass: 'fullscreen-modal',
      onDidPresent: () => {
        dismissLoading();
        isLeadViewerOpening = false
      },
    } );
  }


  const rowSelection = {
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys: React.Key[], selectedRows: LeadPoolDataTypeInterface[]) => {
      console.log(`selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`, 'selectedRows: ', selectedRows);
    }
  };


  return (
    <SideMenuLayout>
      <div className="container lead-pool">

        <section className="gr-p-t-14">
          <h1 className="mb-2">Lead Pool</h1>
          <p>Review all your leads and start marketing to them</p>
        </section>

        <section className="gr-m-t-5">
          <IonCard>
            <IonCardContent>
              <h2>Summary</h2>
            </IonCardContent>
          </IonCard>
        </section>

        <section className="gr-m-t-2">
          <IonCard className="ion-no-margin gr-p-2 gr-p-t-5 gr-p-b-5">
            <IonCardContent>

              <IonRow className="gr-p-b-2">
                <IonButton color="primary"
                           onClick={() => {
                           }}
                >
                  Start to market your leads
                </IonButton>
                <IonButton fill="clear" >
                  Import from CSV
                </IonButton>
                <IonButton fill="clear">
                  Export to CSV
                </IonButton>
              </IonRow>

              <div className="lead-pool__content__datatable">

                <div className="lead-pool__content__datatable__filter">
                  <IonRow>
                    <IonCol className="flex justify-start items-center">
                      <h4 className="gr-p-l-2">Leads</h4>
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol className="flex justify-start items-center">
                      <IonToggle checked={!page.searchAllLeads}
                                 onIonChange={(event) => {
                                   refreshPage({...page, searchAllLeads: !event.detail.checked})
                                 }}
                      >
                        Show leads from all searches
                      </IonToggle>
                    </IonCol>
                    <IonCol className="flex items-center">
                      <IonSearchbar debounce={400}
                                    onIonInput={(ev) => {
                                      const target = ev.target as HTMLIonSearchbarElement;
                                      refreshPage({...page, searchText: target.value});
                                    }}
                      />
                    </IonCol>
                  </IonRow>
                </div>

                <Table
                  className="lead-pool__content__datatable__table"
                  columns={columns}
                  pagination={{
                    current: page.currentPage,
                    pageSize: page.pageSize,
                    total: page.totalDocuments,
                    onChange: (pageNumber) => {
                      refreshPage({...page, currentPage: pageNumber});
                    }
                  }}
                  dataSource={datatable}
                  loading={(datatable == null)}
                />
              </div>
            </IonCardContent>
          </IonCard>
        </section>

        <Disclaimer />

      </div>
    </SideMenuLayout>
  );
};

export default LeadPool;

I want useEffect to run only once. I'm aware of the development double run; that's not the issue.
Sitemap: Dashboard page > Lead Page
When navigating from the dashboard to the lead page, useEffect() runs as expected, triggering refreshPage(). However, if I go back and forth, the lead page API calls accumulate (2, 4, 6, etc.). The dashboard page has a similar useEffect(), but it doesn't pile up requests.
The service has nothing to do with it. Even with console.log's I get the same behavior

Possible causes:

The anonymous function inside useEffect() remains in memory and is
never released.

Something on the page stays in memory, triggering useEffect()
repeatedly.


How can I resolve this?
PS: Obviously, I can't produce a Stackblitz reconstitution of the problem... every other useEffect() in my code behaves as it should. Only THIS one for some reason doesn't want to release the function.
//////////// EDITED (Aug 6 2024) //////////////
As NotX suggested I tried to momoize the refreshPage() function. But it doesn't seems to have any effect.
  const memoizedRefreshPage = useCallback((pageLocal: PageBo) => {
    setDatatable(null);
    services.leadSearchService.getLeadPool(pageLocal).then((leadPoolBo) => {
      setPageLeadBoList(leadPoolBo.leadList);
      setDatatable(generateDatatable(leadPoolBo.leadList));
      setPage({ ...pageLocal, totalDocuments: leadPoolBo.totalDocumentCount });
    });
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
      memoizedRefreshPage(page);
  }, []);

In the same line of thinking, I tried to cache the result of the "leadSearchService" service
export class LeadSearchService {
     
  private _cachedPageBo: PageBo;
  private _cachedLeadPoolBo: LeadPoolBo;

  constructor(
    private leadSearchClient: LeadSearchClient,
  ) {}


  public async getLeadPool( pageBo: PageBo ): Promise<LeadPoolBo> {
    const leadPool: GetLeadPoolResponseDto = await this.leadSearchClient.getLeadPoolList(new GetLeadPoolRequestDto({
      leadPoolId: pageBo.leadPoolId,
      searchText: pageBo.searchText,
      currentPage: pageBo.currentPage,
      pageSize: pageBo.pageSize,
      searchAllLeads: pageBo.searchAllLeads,
    }));
    return new LeadPoolBo({
      leadList: leadPool.leadList.map( lead => new LeadBo(lead) ),
      totalDocumentCount: leadPool.totalDocumentCount,
    });
  }


  public async getCachedLeadPool( pageBo: PageBo ): Promise<LeadPoolBo> {
    if( this._cachedPageBo && isEqual(pageBo, this._cachedPageBo) ) {
      return this._cachedLeadPoolBo;
    }
    this._cachedLeadPoolBo = await this.getLeadPool(pageBo);
    this._cachedPageBo = pageBo;
    return this._cachedLeadPoolBo;
  }

At first, I thought I had fixed the problem... but as soon as I visited another "lead pool page"...

As you can see they all come back at once with a vengeance ><"
Any idea?

Something which might be worth a shot: can you create a memoized version of refreshPage with the useCallback hook, and add this memoized refreshPage as as useEffect dependency? This would be the formally correcty way (or you have to move the refreshPage declaration into the useEffect callback). That said, I'm not conviced that this formal correctness makes a difference here, but it doesn't harm to check it out.

@NotX Very good idea, I tried to implement your suggestion, you can see the new code in my post but it doesn't seem to have any effect :(

How are you rendering the above component / how are you handling the page routing? What happens if you strip down your component to just have an effect with your logs, does that still cause the multiple accumulating logs? If you add a cleanup function to your effect, do you see that being invoked?

Your previous post was closed and later deleted. This appears to be a re-post with no new details or information really. You even got the same first answer pointing to the StrictMode component. How are you rendering this LeadPool component? My best guess is that maybe you are somehow creating or rendering duplicate "instances" of the component when navigating around and they are all mounting and running that effect. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve].

If you're in development mode, reactjs runs hooks like useEffect twice to make it easier to catch potential errors. You can check whether this is the cause by commenting React.StrictMode in App.js

I already explained in my post: "I want useEffect to run only once. I'm aware of the development double run; that's not the issue." but thank you for you suggestion it did blocked me at the beginning of the project
